# how to echo contents of wordpress loop as one variable outside loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

im using shortcode in a php template file for wordpress, because the shortcode opens and closes I need to get the entire content within it as one variable. In this case the content is a wordpress loop.

So far what I have only displays the final post of the loop. I understand why, as that is what the final value of the variable is. Im wondering could someone help me get the entire contents (ie all three posts) into a variable, as oppose to just the final post.

Thanks

```
<?php 
                $news_title .= '';
                $news_single_post .= '';

            if ( have_posts() ) :
            $the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'cat' => 1 ) ); /*  */
             while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php 
                $news_title = get_the_title();
                $news_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                $news_single_post = '<div class="home-content-news-title">'.$news_title.'</div><div class="home-content-news-excerpt">'.$news_excerpt.'</div>';

                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();

                endif; 



                $news_tab_title_string = 'News';
                $news_tab_title_shortcode = do_shortcode('[wptabtitle]'.$news_tab_title_string.'[/wptabtitle]');
                $news_tab_content_shortcode = do_shortcode('[wptabcontent]'.$news_single_post.'[/wptabcontent]');
                $news_tab = $news_tab_title_shortcode.$news_tab_content_shortcode;
                echo do_shortcode('[wptabs]'.$news_tab.'[/wptabs]');

         ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the variable you want all of the content to go into above and outside the loop e.g. `$variable = '';`, and then within the loop concatenate to that variable using `$variable .= $content_to_concat;` and then use `echo $variable;` outside of the loop at the end to print the entire contents.

Your code as an example:

```
<?php 
    $news_title .= '';
    $news_single_post .= '';
    $news_all_posts = ''; // Define the variable

    if ( have_posts() ) :
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'cat' => 1 ) ); /*  */

    while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

    $news_title = get_the_title();
    $news_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $news_single_post = '<div class="home-content-news-title">'.$news_title.'</div><div class="home-content-news-excerpt">'.$news_excerpt.'</div>';

    $news_all_posts .= $news_single_post; // Add each post to the variable

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;

    $news_tab_title_string = 'News';
    $news_tab_title_shortcode = do_shortcode('[wptabtitle]'.$news_tab_title_string.'[/wptabtitle]');

    // Use the variable to display the content
    $news_tab_content_shortcode = do_shortcode('[wptabcontent]'.$news_all_posts.'[/wptabcontent]');

    $news_tab = $news_tab_title_shortcode.$news_tab_content_shortcode;
    echo do_shortcode('[wptabs]'.$news_tab.'[/wptabs]');
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Maccath, that worked perfectly. Can I just ask for the sake of learning...
I decided to leave out the `$news_all_posts` variable and just define `$news_single_post = '';`, and then within the loop I wrote `news_single_post .= ............`, this worked too. 

Just wondering is there anything wrong with what I did? The only reason I did it was to reduce the amount of variables and keep it neater, but im only learning so maybe Im missing something obvious, thanks for the help.

Comment: What you did is fine, though I would have removed `$news_single_post` and just used `$news_all_posts` instead as `$news_single_post` now contains all posts so the name doesn't match its contents - it's best practice to always use relevant variable names as well as remove unnecessary variables.